# Upgrade from centoS 6.10 to what OS for OTRS/Znuny?

Tags: linux, otrs

I have a centOS 6.10 installation which needs a upgrade to a newer CentOS.
But since CentOS support will be dropped for LTS I have now to decide to which path to switch.

I need long term support for installed linux package regarding security updates. And CentOS did a good job on this.

Can anyone tell me, what the best distro alternative for OTRS/Znuny to use?
Rocky Linux? Alma Linux or maybe even something else?

Comment: First decide if you're using OTRS or Znuny! These are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

You must make the decision about what distribution to use.

Are you able to deploy your applications on the distro? Do you trust the maintainers to provide timely security updates for the life of the release?

Maybe a dozen RHEL clones exist, per [DistroWatch](https://distrowatch.com/search.php?basedon=Red%20Hat) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_derivatives). Fedora and derivatives if you are fine with moving fast and upgrading every year, but perhaps not if CentOS Stream is too fast for you. Many more if you do not limit yourself to Red Hat. Even more if you are not limited to Linux and can try say one of the BSDs.